# Where can I find documentation for the File->New->Package window?

Tags: front-end, packages

I'm using 10.0.0 on OS X. When I go File->New->Package a window similar to a notebook appears, but with different coloration and a row of buttons on the top like 'Update' and 'Run Package'. I'm not sure what the 'Update' button does, for example.

I'd like to learn how to write packages: Where can I find documentation on how to use this window effectively? What would it even be called? (Does anyone use this window?)

Comment: Not about the window, but about packages: [wolframpackages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html). Try the example in the window and see how it works out.